# If $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, then $m^2 + n^2 = c$, and vice versa. Why?

Tags: number-theory

I was thinking a bit about Pythagoras' equation and the general form of pythagorean triples and found it quite interesting  how if $c$ can be expressed as the sum of two squares, then $c^2$ can as well.

And while I'm at it, might as well also ask why $c$ is prime and $c \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ for this equation to hold (Fermat's theorem, I believe).

Some things I tried:

$(m^2 + n^2)^2 = c^2 = m^4 + 2m^2n^2 + n^4$, but I don't know how to express the second equation as the sum of two squares.

Comment: If $c=m^2+n^2$, surely you realize you can use this $m,n$ and plug it into the formula $(m^2-n^2)^2+(2mn)^2=(m^2+n^2)^2$ to find the corresponding $a,b$?

Comment: It may be false unless you demand $\gcd(a,b) = 1.$ For example, $9^2 + 12 ^2 = 15^2,$ but $15$ is not the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 2):

Seem to be a few misunderstandings. First, the thing may be false unless $\gcd(a,b) = 1.$ For example, $9^2 + 12^2 = 15^2,$ while $15$ is not the sum of two squares.

IF $\gcd(a,b) = 1:$

Theorem (A): given any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ if $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ then $x \equiv 0 \pmod q$ and $y \equiv 0 \pmod q,$ so $\gcd(x,y) \neq 1$ because $q | \gcd(x,y) $

Theorem (B, Fermat): $p=2$ and any $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ can be written with integers as $p = u^2 + v^2,$ with $\gcd(u,v)=1.$

Theorem(C) If we have  $m $ which is not divisible by $4$ or by any prime  $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$   then we have also  $m = x^2 + y^2$ with $\gcd(x,y) = 1.$ Proof by Brahmagupta, and induction on the number of primes dividing $m.$ Note that is is allowed for $m$ to have repeated prime factors. A certain amount of care is required, also a $\pm$ choice in Brahmagupta. Finally, this includes even $m$ as long as it is not divisible by $4.$

Put these together: given odd $c$ with $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ with $\gcd(a,b) = 1,$ it follows from Theorem (A) that $c^2$ is not divisible by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ By unique factorization, also $c$ itself is not divisible by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ By Theorems (B) and (C), it follows that we can write $c = g^2 + h^2,$ with $\gcd(g,h) = 1.$

EEDDIIITTT: proof of (A). Somebody, maybe Gauss, maybe before, realized that $-1$ is not a quadratic residue for any prime  $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$ The set of elements $\pmod q$ still make a field. If $$x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q,$$ then 
$$x^2  \equiv -y^2 \pmod q.$$ ASSUME that $y \neq 0 \pmod q.$ Then it and $y^2$ have multiplicative inverses in the field. So
$$ \frac{x^2}{y^2}  \equiv -1 \pmod q,$$ or
$$ \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^2 \equiv -1 \pmod q.$$ This makes $-1$ a square, impossible, and contradicts the assumption that $y$ was not divisible by $q.$ So, actually, $q | y,$ and $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod q$ then tells us that $q | x$ as well. Thus, $q | \gcd(x,y).$

Comment: Can you please justify theorem $A$?